# .tif file conversion to .bil format

Tags: r, raster-conversion

I want to convert .tif files I have downloaded from the worldclim database to .bil format which is required by landscape genomics package.

I can use some of the R spatial packages.

Comment: What software do you have? You tagged ArcGIS, but then you say in a comment to an answer that you don't have it! What have you tried? What didn't work? Please [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/354337/edit) the question to add more details

Comment: I am working with R and some packages like rspatial

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the tif file into an R object and save it as a .bil file.

```
> library(raster)
> r = raster("r.tif")
> writeRaster(r,"r.bil")
>
```

Note this results in three new files, with the data and some header metadata, I imagine:

```
r.bil: data
r.hdr: ASCII text
r.stx: ASCII text
```

If you have the gdal tools installed or the R `gdalUtils` package you can do it directly with `gdal_translate` at the command line (not the R command line):

```
$ gdal_translate -of EHDR r.tif rr.bil
Input file size is 4, 3
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
```

again, you get a .bil and a .hdr. The .hdr is an Esri Header file, which is where the output format `EHDR` gets its name from.

Comment: thank you @Spacedman, I will go over see if it works for me. I hope it will. cheers,

Comment: yes it worked. big thanks!!!!!

Comment: @Girma, please check of Spacedman's answer to mark that it solved your problem - that makes it more usable for somebody checking in later :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use ArcGIS's CopyRaster_management tool. Use your .tif file as the input raster, and use the .bil extension for the name of the output raster.

Comment: Thank you. but can I use R since I do not have ArcGIS and don't know much how to work with it?

Comment: @Girma If you tag a question `arcgis-desktop` and don't specify otherwise in the body of the question, you're requesting an ArcGIS answer. Please edit the question to include your preferred software stack, tag it appropriately, and include your attempt at a solution (with details about the error encountered).